# What does passing curly braces as a function argument mean?

Tags: c++, c++17

In C++17 code, I sometimes see something like:

```
void myfunction(const std::string& arg1, int arg2) {
  //...
}

void otherfunction() {
  myfunction("a",1);
  myfunction({},2);
  myfunction("b",{});
  myfunction({},{});
}
```

What do the empty curly brace arguments means?

I found that I get an empty string and 0 integer, so I suppose it's some kind of default value.

Comment: Note that this is nothing new in c++17 and was introduced in c++11

Comment: The parameters are initialized by the argument ; so the function is set up as if you went `const std::string& arg1 = {}; int arg2 = 2;` and so on

Comment: You wrote "I found that I get an empty string and 0 integer, so I suppose it's some kind of default value."  -- So, you already found the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This was introduced in C++17 and is called [*list-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

When the braces are empty, it will perform [*value initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization):

For scalar types such as `int`, it will be as if you define it in global scope, i.e it will be [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) (also true for class instances with default constructor that is not user-provided and not deleted, unless it has a non-trivial default constructor in which case it will be default initialized).

If class type with no default constructor or if the default constructor has been marked deleted, it will perform [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) (ex. `T t;`), this is also true if there is a user defined constructor.

Examples:

```
struct A {
  A() : x{1}, y{2} {}

  int x,y;
};

/* A has a default user-provided constructor,
 * calls default constructor */
A a{};
//////////////////////////

struct B {
  B() {}

  int x, y;
  string z;
};
/* B has a user defined default constructor,
 * since x and y are not mentioned in the initializer list,
 * B::x and B::y contain intermediate values,
 * while, B::z will be default initialized to "" */
B b{};
//////////////////////////

struct C {
  int x, y;
};
/* C has an implicit default constructor,
 * C::x and C::y will be zero-initialized */
C c{};
//////////////////////////
```